# Any way to improve this String comparison with Java?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;



public class NNNTest {
private String SkillNeed="Java;C++;C";
private String SkillHave="SQL:8;Java:9;C++:5;C:9;PHP:5";

public boolean CheckAvailable(){
    int flag=0; 
    int k;
    String [] snar=SkillNeed.split(";");
    String [] shandlevel=SkillHave.split(";");


    for(int i=0;i<snar.length;i++){
        for(k=0,flag=0;k<shandlevel.length;k++){
            if(shandlevel[k].split(":")[0].equals(snar[i])){
                System.out.println(shandlevel[k].split(":")[0]);
                flag=1;
            }
        }
        if(flag==0){
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag==1){
        System.out.println("YES");
        return true;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("NO");
        return false;
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NNNTest n=new NNNTest();
    n.CheckAvailable();


}
}
```

The method check if you have enough skills to acquire the job.

SkillNeed is a String that with form  "skill;skill;skill....."

SkillHave is the skills and level you have and with form  "skill:level;skill:level;...."

These are the codes that I typed,but I think it's pretty long and boring,do you have any other way to improve the method?Something like skipping the loop or Array or using java given methods.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on codereview instad.

Comment: @Flow While you are right that this question would be better on codereview it doesn't mean it is off-topic on SO.

Comment: Besides, it's not actually correct. It returns false despite the user having all three skills.

Comment: I have updated the code,it works well now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply way with java-8:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class NNNTest {

    private static String skillNeed = "Java;C++;C"; //the skills the job need
    private static String skillHave = "SQL:8;Java:9;C++:5;C:9;PHP:5"; //skill and level you have

    public static boolean checkAvailable() { //if all the job needed skills match the skills you have
        return Arrays.stream(skillHave.split(";")).map(s -> s.split(":")[0]).collect(Collectors.toSet()).containsAll(Arrays.asList(skillNeed.split(";")));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(checkAvailable());
    }
}
```

Edited for explanation:

1. Collect al skillHave in a Set (without the number).
2. Check if the Set of skillHave contains all elements of a given collection.
3. Collect all SkillNeed in another Set and pass it as parameter for previous step.

Comment: This is a really good example of solving this task, but, I think, @Feng will not understand this without explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Another Java 8 Solution..
It basically iterates through all required skills and makes sure, using the allMatch() function, that each skill is contained in the givenSkills-String. Keep in mind, that you have to check for ":" aswell, otherwise "C" would also match "C++". This also makes sure, that it exactly matches the skill, since the skill is either at the beginning, or it is enclosed by ; and :.

```
public static boolean checkForRequiredSkills(String requiredSkills, String givenSkills)
{
    return Arrays.stream(requiredSkills.split(";")).allMatch(skill -> givenSkills.startsWith(skill + ":") || givenSkills.contains(";" + skill + ":"));
}
```

A similar solution in earlier java versions could be looking like this

```
public boolean checkAvailable()
{
    for (String skill : skillNeed.split(";"))
    {
        if (!skillNeed.startsWith(skill + ":") && !skillHave.contains(";" + skill + ":"))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Also the preferred idiom, to iterate over an Array or List is using a for-each loop..

```
for(String str : stringArray)
doSomething(str);
```

Comment: Edited the code a little bit...Might not be the best solution, should give a brief idea...